# Payment service with API

Tags: online-payment

I'm planing to build a site where users can buy products from local business, what I'm looking for is a payment API where the user pays for the product and the payment goes to the business's account, I've been searching but all I see are services to accept payment for your own shop/service. What I need is to redirect the payment to the business offering the product.

Requirements:

- Payment is handled by the service, not too much security responsibility for me.
- As parameters, I just send both bank accounts, amount, currency.
- The service must redirect the payment to the business account offering the product, not to my account.
- It should work for credit and debit cards, and for acounts outside of the U.S (specialy Mexico and latin america).

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about *software,* not *service* recommendation (see: [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185))

Comment: @Izzy If it has an API why is it different from other software.

Comment: Loki, your question explicitly asks for the service ("what I'm looking for is a payment service"). It would indeed be different if it were asking for an API to a specific service, but it isn't. For what's the difference, please follow the link in my previous comment, where all this is discussed.

Comment: I can not imagine a service like that without an API, just going to edit the post to make it explicit.

Comment: @loki I improved the question by adding requirements, feel free to edit them to describe your real requirements better.

Comment: @lzzy: See [this answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/686/1822) on the link you just posted.  Loki's question seems reasonable as far as that's concerned (even in the case of his original question, though the latter violated other guidelines).

Comment: @Izzy if it does not fit here, migrate it to webapps.se or webmasters.se, perfect fit there

Comment: @Fischer if you are not used to any of those sites please don't recommend them, [webmaster.se] [help page](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically say "Recommendations for sites and resources" and [webapps.se] has a [similar post](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2595/43673)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at https://stripe.com/, they have a pretty straight forward API. They offer a variety of SDKs and it is also possible to use CURL.

Regarding your requirements:

That is what a payment provider does, it stores all payment data for you, so you do not have to worry about PCI Standards and other Security Issues.

The API works just as you suggested. You can send account data, security keys, subject to Stripe and they will do the clearing for you.

I worked with other solutions like Saferpay, which is a drag. You cannot do without security keys, which you have to import in your JVM and whatnot. Moreover, their API is far from standards based.

Talking about responses, it is clear that the API will respond to you with the result of the transaction.

Comment: This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed.